# So many types of subwords! How are they called?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $\mathscr F(X)$ be the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on an alphabet $X$, the carrier set of $\mathscr F(X)$ being the union of $X^{\times k}$ (the Cartesian product of $k$ copies of $X$) as $k$ ranges over $\mathbb N$ (the non-negative integers). We will refer to an element of $\mathscr F(X)$ as an *$X$-word*; and use the symbol $\ast$ for the operation (of *word concatenation*) in $\mathscr F(X)$ and $\varepsilon$ for the *empty word* (namely, the identity of $\mathscr F(X)$).

Given an $X$-word $\mathfrak u$, there is a unique $k \in \mathbb N$, called the (*word*) *length* of $\mathfrak u$ and herein denoted by $\|\mathfrak u\|$, such that $\mathfrak u \in X^{\times k}$: If $k \ge 1$, then there are uniquely determined $x_1, \ldots, x_k \in X$ (named the *letters* of $\mathfrak u$) such that $\mathfrak u = x_1 \ast \cdots \ast x_k$; and for each index $i \in [\![ 1, k ]\!]$ (the discrete interval between $1$ and $k$), we write $\mathfrak u[i]$ for the $i$-th letter of $\mathfrak u$.

Now suppose that $\mathfrak v$ and $\mathfrak w$ are both $X$-words. There are at least three (alternative) ways to define what it means for $\mathfrak v$ to be a *subword* of $\mathfrak w$:

1. $\mathfrak v$ *divides* $\mathfrak w$ in $\mathscr F(X)$, that is, $\mathfrak w = \mathfrak s \ast \mathfrak v \ast \mathfrak t$ for some $\mathfrak s, \mathfrak t \in \mathscr F(X)$.
2. There is a (strictly) increasing function $\sigma \colon [\![1, \|\mathfrak v\| ]\!] \to [\![1, \|\mathfrak w\| ]\!]$ such that $\mathfrak v[i] = \mathfrak w[\sigma(i)]$ for each $i \in [\![1, \|\mathfrak v\| ]\!]$ (note that this condition is vacuously satisfied when $\mathfrak v = \varepsilon$).
3. Same as the previous definition, except that $\sigma$ is required to be injective (rather than increasing).

**My question is** whether there is any *well-established* terminology that makes it possible to distinguish each kind of subword from the others. I've seen subwords of type 2 being called *scattered subwords* (and I myself am sticking to this term in my writings).

***Edit 1.*** In a comment to the OP, Vladimir Dotsenko asked, "Does the situation 3 really appear in a meaningful way?" Here, I'll try to address his question.

Suppose that $X$ is a subset of a (multiplicatively written) monoid $H$. An *$X$-factorization* of an element $h \in H$ is then an $X$-word $\mathfrak u$ such that $h = \pi(\mathfrak u)$, where $\pi$ is the (so-called) *factorization homomorphism* of $H$, namely, the unique extension of the identity function on $H$ to a monoid homomorphism $\mathscr F(H) \to H$. For various reasons, it is somehow interesting (from the point of view of the arithmetic theory of monoids) to endow $H$ with a *preorder* (i.e., a reflexive and transitive binary relation) $\preceq$ and to look at the $X$-factorizations of an element $h \in H$ that are minimal with respect to the (so-called) *shuffling preorder* $\sqsubseteq$, that is, the binary relation on $\mathscr F(H)$ defined by $\mathfrak u \sqsubseteq \mathfrak v$, for some $H$-words $\mathfrak u$ and $\mathfrak v$, if and only if there is an injective function $\sigma \colon [\![ 1, \|\mathfrak u\| ]\!] \to [\![ 1, \|\mathfrak v\| ]\!]$ such that $\mathfrak u[i] \preceq \mathfrak v[\sigma(i)] \preceq \mathfrak u[i]$ for each $i \in [\![ 1, \|\mathfrak u\| ]\!]$. Minimal $X$-factorizations can then be used to forge the notions of 'minimal unique factorization', 'minimal factorization length', etc., which (generalize and) work somewhat better than the corresponding notions in the *classical* theory (where the preorder $\preceq$ is the *divisibility preorder* on $H$ and $\sqsubseteq$ is (almost always) implicitly assumed to be the relation of $\sqsubseteq$-equivalence), especially in those situations where the nature of $H$ gives rise to 'blow-up phenomena' that make classical 'metric invariants' (such as sets of lengths and their unions, elasticities, distances, etc.) essentially meaningless. Note, in particular, that two $X$-words are $\sqsubseteq$-equivalent if and only if one is a permutation of the other modulo $\preceq$-equivalence: This is ultimately a generalization of the fact that, in the basic setting of the integers under multiplication, two prime factorizations of the same element are considered the same if and only if they differ only in the order of the factors and up to associates.

Comment: Does the situation 3 really appear in a meaningful way? Whenever I saw situations where 1 needed to be distinguished from 2, I recall 1 being described as a subword while 2 referred to as a subsequence.

Comment: Lothaire's Combinatorics on words uses "factor" for 1 (Chapter 5) and "subword" for 2 (Chapter 6). It may or may not be an exception, but be careful out there.

Comment: I now notice the actual question. As far as I know, "factor" (when speaking of the factor of a word) can only mean 1 as far as I know. And as far as I know, "scattered subword" and "subsequence" can only mean 2. I think they are all "well-established", but I don't have statistics to back that up. I can't think of an unambiguous standard name for 3.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Of course, a word is a (finite) sequence in $X$ and hence it makes sense to call a subword of type 2 a subsequence. But this is sort of mixing two different pts of view (after all, I'm referring to a word as a word and not as a sequence). As for situations where subwords of type 3 appear in a meaningful way, it's probably better if I edit the OP and address your question therein (but later, I'm a bit busy now).

Comment: @VilleSalo To me, "factor" makes a lot of sense for subwords of type 1, so one may want to talk of "factor subwords" in that case: A lot of people out there simply use the term "subword" (without any qualifier) for subwords of type 1 (as was also pointed out by Vladimir Dotsenko in his comment). But I really need to distinguish the three types in some situations that naturally occur in my research area.

Comment: Subword / scattered subword seems like a good enough pair. As for 3, combinatorics on word-ists sometimes throw around the word "abelian" when you take take a standard notion but also take anagrams (I don't know why they don't speak of "anagrams" given how much they talk about "palindromes"). So "abelian scattered subword" sounds relatively unambiguous to me. (And also horrible, sorry I'm not very helpful.)

Comment: @VilleSalo I very much like this idea of "anagrams". One could maybe talk of subanagrams in case of subwords of type 3.

Comment: The standard terminology in combinatorics on words is factor for 1, scattered subword for 2.  I don't know a term for 3. Abelian subword usually means the letters appear consecutively but in a different order I believe

Comment: French mathematicians often use subword for scattered subword and non-French mathematicians often use subword for factor

Comment: P.S. You might also find useful that in studying a similar story for permutations rather than words, there is its own terminology: type 1 is referred to as "consecutive pattern", while type 2 is simply "pattern".

Comment: At the end of the day, I think I won't get away with anything better than what has already emerged from the previous comments. If someone is willing to post a summary of the information collected so far, I'll be happy to accept it as an answer.